# Application exits as soon as its started in AIR

Tags: air, adobe, flash-builder, blackberry-playbook

I just started developing for BlackBerry PlayBook with Adobe AIR and Adobe Flash Builder 4.6

For learning, I started to follow the [Tutorial from BlackBerry](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/air/documentation/ww_air_developing/cs_using_containers_design_layout_ms_1970871_11.html) and I copied the code exactly as it is. And when I run the application, it shows the icon in the PlayBook simulator. But as soon as I click it, the BlackBerry logo is shown in middle of a black box for about 1 second and it dissapears. (i.e. the app exits as soon as its launched).

Any idea why this is?  Please note that I'm completely new to Adobe products and PlayBook development.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking "Debug" button in the Flash Builder and watch the output in console closely

Comment: When I press the debug button, Flash Builder shows a progress bar filling _very_ slowly (its fast when "running" normally). Then it displays an error message **The Flash Builder debugger failed to connect to the running application.
Ensure that:.....** and shows some advice that I have already done. Please help!

Comment: Have you installed a debug token? https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/air/documentation/ww_air_testing/create_a_debug_token_fb_ms_1968146_11.html

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a debug token on the PlayBook, make sure it didn't expire.